# CouchDB 2.0 404 on Mango Server - GET /db/_index

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I am using CouchDB 2.0 and receiving a 404 when trying to get the index definition on my production database.

Similarly, I receive a 400 Bad Request when using `POST /db/_find` and `POST /db/_index`  against production.

These both work on my development server (Mac OSX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB 2.0 does not work over SSL unless you use HAProxy.  I was not using HAProxy and various CouchDB features would fail when accessing the admin API via SSL.

Suggestion is to use HAProxy to manage SSL.

https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-connect-via-https/48657/27